# Cannot Find my AWS Reserved Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I bought an AWS reserved instance last week and I saw it on the Reserved Instances page on the AWS Management Console. Now, I can't find it! At all! It's like I never bought it. The only 'proof' that I bought it can be seen on the accounts activity page, showing my payment for the instance (medium type instance BTW). What's even more annoying is that I cannot contact AWS for help except I buy a support package. I'd hate to pay for support to fix an error I think they caused. Not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 3):

a reserved instance is just a billing term. If you have a medium instance running it will pick a medium instance to use for the billing terms.

If there are no medium instances running that it might have been retired. That happens if you don't pay attention to your email. Sometimes with ec2 is the hardware suffers a failure so they retire everyone's ec2 instances on that hardware. They send out an email with a retire date. Another thing is the hardware might have just died quickly so no warning email was sent out and it's now just gone.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike. I just checked my inbox (and spam). I can't find any mail from AWS advising me of a hardware failure or on anything concerning this puzzle.

Comment: it might have just failed hard then so they didn't send anything out. I've had it happen before.

Comment: So what did you do? Do I have a choice other than buying support? How do I notify them?

Comment: try their support forums. Their support team is pretty active there

Comment: Geez! I went to the forum and before posting, did a search for similar queries. Didn't exactly get my answer but something about regions came up in one for the posts. Then it occurred to me to check the region I was viewing - it was the wrong one. I changed that and - problem solved - I found my stuff. I'm not sure though, why the Management Console took me to the 'wrong' region by default, seeing I had nothing there and have some stuff in another region.

Comment: always the easy answer :)